# Як перекласти "return type"

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Намагаюсь зрозуміти як можна перекласти *return type* в сенсі типу значення, яке повертає функція. Наприклад:

```
int f() { return 0; }
```

Тут *return type* це `int`. Тобто, ми повертаємо `0`, який має тип `int`.

Наразі маємо статтю з назвою [тип повернення значення функції](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97), але назва якась недолуга як на мене, імовірно намагались перекласти російське *тип возвращаемого значения*.

*return type* має синонім *result type*, можливо варто просто використати *тип результату* і не намагатись перекласти *return type*?

Comment: Усталеного перекладу термінів із сфери програмування в українській, по суті, немає. Наскільки мені відомо немає жодного словника із технічними термінами та із технічними термінами із сфери програмування зокрема. Зазвичай, просто іде калькування з російської/англійської. Будь-яка відповідь, яку тут можуть дати і на всі питання такого типу - буде абсолютно суб'єктивною(принаймні на 2019 рік), оскільки кожний, більше чи менше, перекладає так як йому звичніше(хтось буде більше калькувати із російської, більшість буде калькувати із англійської), бо стандартів немає.

Comment: Навіть чинні переклади таких технічних слів на різних сайтах часто відрізняється. Рандомний приклад: слово `strict mode` в документації Реакту перекладається як `суворий режим`, а в документації JavaScript в MDN перекладається як `строгий режим`. Приклад не дуже наочний, але я думаю ви засвоїли суть.

Comment: @improbable мене влаштує суб'єктивна, добре, щоб вона містила логічне обгрунтування.

Comment: @Yola я б переклад як _повoрoтниј тип_ (_зворотниј, повертниј_), також існує, як бачу сутямоковиј вираз _result type_, тоді _результатниј тип_. Можна, зьвісно перекласти на родовиј відмінок: _тип результату_, _тип повороту_ (_звороту, поверту_).

Comment: @stegetsj мабуть, дійсно ваші варіанти найкращі. Трохи засмучує, що без контексту неможна відрізнити поворот в сенсі на кут і додому.

Comment: Серйозно? Це тема для дослідження? Це просто ганьба.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko дуже люблю критику, вона допомагає мені покращити себе. Чи не могли б ви уточнити, що саме вам не подобається? Дякую!

Comment: Інформаційні технології - це аналогії з життя (з інших галузей), переважно. В даному випадку функція з математики. Методи - аналогія об'єкту та його властивостей. І так далі. Тобто почитайте що таке функція в математиці і ви отримаєте свої відповіді. Тип значення функції. Тип вихідних даних. Дослівно, повернений тип або тип результату. Але і тут можна покритикувати щодо послідовності слів дослівності.

Comment: "Наразі маємо статтю з назвою тип повернення значення функції" - це машинний переклад.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko так, а чому ганьба?

Comment: Бо просто знайти відповідь на це запитання. Як ви шукали? Що ви шукали? Я не розумію як можна не знайти відповідь на це запитання самому. Мабуть дуже різко написав.

Comment: @stegetsj можливо, ще *тип висліду* і інші варіації від *вислід*.

Answer (score 5):

*return type* -  це англійське словосполучення, яке здебільшого використовується у сфері програмування.

Переклад цього словосполучення - тип, який повертається/віддається/вертається.
 
Скорочено від: тип, який повертає/віддає/вертає функція/метод.
В даному контексті, тип - це [тип даних](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85), проте, у 99% випадків, говорять просто тип. Також, майже ніколи не говорять, що тип повертається/віддається/вертається функцією або методом.

> Наразі маємо статтю з назвою тип повернення значення функції, але назва якась недолуга як на мене, імовірно намагались перекласти російське тип возвращаемого значения.

Тип повернення значення функції - абсолютне калькування, проте, я вважаю, що аналог цього виразу як *тип значення, яке повертає/віддає/вертає функція/метод* має право на існування.

Ось і виходить:
*return type* - тип(значення/даних), який повертається/віддається/вертається (функцією/методом).
З точки зору англійської мови, слово *return* зазвичай перекладають як *повертати*, тому, більшість людей схильна перекладати як *тип, який повертається*.

Зрештою, рішення яку комбінацію слів обирати для перекладу цього словосполучення - залишається за мовцем, адже не існує жодного систематизованого джерела з усталеними словами-аналогами технічних закордонних термінів, особливо із сфери програмування(ситуація на 2019 рік).
На жаль, у даному випадку, все зводиться до суб'єктивізму.

*Примітка 1:* Термін *result type* я ніколи не зустрічав як синонім слова *return type*, незважаючи на факт того, що слово *result type* надзвичайно рідко вживається в спільноті.
*Примітка 2:* Переклад абсолютно суб'єктивний і відображає власний переклад автора вищезгаданого словосполучення згідно особистих переконань та досвіду в спільноті/сфері.

**Необхідне доповнення із коментарів, важливе для людей далеких від програмування:**
*return type*, як мінімум, в 90% випадках, не є результатом виконання функції/методу або є лише частиною! Це зрозуміло усім людям, котрі програмують. *return type* або є або немає, це тип даних, які функція зобов'язана повернути в мовах зі статичною типізацією(Java, C++, C# і т.д.), вказавши це в своїй сигнатурі(означення методу). В мовах із динамічною типізацією(Python, JavaScript і т.д.), тип даних, що повертається, не оголошується в сигнатурі функції і тому тип даних, котрий повертається, визначається динамічно, під час виконання програми, це може бути що-завгодно; тип даних, що повертається в цьому випадку є неозначеним.

Незалежно від того, що повертає функція - усі зміни, виконані під час роботи функції надзвичайно рідко будуть повністю відображатися в даних(це лише в 99% дійсне для менш популярних функціональних мов та і то лише якщо дотримуватися функціональної парадигми програмування). Ті дані, які повертає функція/метод, зазвичай, є мінімальними даними необхідними для продовження роботи програми або задуманого функціонування.

Я не говорю за старі програми; мови програмування, які зараз не використовуються; неякісний код в проектах і застарілі підходи для програмування.
В усіх сучасних підходах до програмування, це залізне правило.

Таким чином, "return type" - це явна або неявна частина визначення функції, яка, зазвичай, дуже слабко корелюється із повним результатом виконання функції.

Comment: "Тип повернення значення функції - абсолютне калькування" - це не калькування, це робот перекладач. Вдумайтеся що там написано.

Answer (score 2):

В коді команду **return 0;** треба читати в наказовій формі. Як "**повернути 0**". Бо програма - це перелік наказів.

Ця команда визначає область значень функції в залежності від описаних умов, визначень, вхідних даних та команд цієї функції.

Повернене значення може мати певний [**тип**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B2_C%2B%2B#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85), який визначає метод зберігання змінної в пам'яті.

Переклад **return type** залежить від змісту використання в реченні.

Якщо перейти за вказаним посиланням і обрати англійську мову, то можна побачити зміст.

In computer programming, **the return type** (or result type) defines ... - В комп'ютерному програмуванні, **повернений тип** (або ж тип результату) визначає ...

Як зрозуміліший варіант можна використати детальніший опис "**тип значення поверненої змінної з функції**".

Answer (score 1):

Ось результати з [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9&scope=all&highlight=on):

> **Возвращаемый** – (*способн. пас., возвратимый*) повертни́й; (*в пас. действии*) ве́ртаний, пове́ртаний:
> • *возвращаемое значение (функции) – (комп.)* значення повернення (вертання) (функції);
> • *возвращаемый аппарат – (косм.)* пове́ртаний (повертни́й) аппарат;
> • *возвращаемый (сейчас) документ* – вертаний (тепер) документ. Обговорення статті
> <sub>Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–</sub>

> **возвращающийся/возвраща́емый** пове́ртаний, по́воро́тець, прикм. поворотни́й;
> <sub>Російсько-український словник складної лексики С. Караванський, 2012 (чернетка)</sub>

Отже, можливо також можна *вертаний/повертаний тип*.

Comment: Ось один зразок поганого, неякісного допису, який навіть не намагається відповідати на запитання. Ресурс r2u перекладає з московського «русского» язика. Словосполучення "return type" — це англійська. Нема ніяких лінгвістичних причин перекладати її через московську. Чом не з китайської, наприклад?

Comment: -1, бо автор за 2 тижні не відреагував на коментар з метою порятунку цього допису.

Comment: Звірення і порівняння з іншими мовами під час пошуку перекладу — дуже цікавий, розумний, різносторонній та творчий підхід до справи. На жаль, не певен щодо якості кінцевого результату у цій відповіді, але сам підхід вартий уваги, бо вчить шукати відповіді у широшому класі питань, тому +1

Answer (score 0):

```
тип результату
```

Враховуючи те, що по суті це мабуть найбільш точно передає значення в контексті програмування

Comment: Так, це те на, що, мабуть, доведеться погодитись. Але це не дуже вдалий варіант, бо результат роботи функція може й не повертати, тобто можуть бути якісь побічні ефекти або ж зміни в аргументах.

Comment: @Yola В сигнатурі функції пишеться, який тип даних вона повертає. Це не лотерея, наперед відомо, що метод поверне, якщо ми говоримо про мову програмування із статичною типізацією, синтаксис якої ви вказали в питанні.

Comment: Саме так, пишеться тип даних, що вона повертає, але те, що функція повертає може не бути всім результатом роботи функції. Наприклад, результатом роботи програми може бути зміна [глобального стану](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Comment: @Yola А хто стверджував, що `return type` -  це результат роботи програми?! Це аж ніяк не одне і те ж саме. `return type` або є або немає, це тип даних, які функція зобов'язана повернути(в мовах зі статичною типізацією), вказавши це в своїй сигнатурі, це частина функції, а не частина класу/ більш широкого скопу. Незалежно від того, що повертає функція - усі зміни, виконані під час роботи функції надзвичайно рідко будуть відображатися в даних, які повертає функція, функція буде повертати лише те, що ДІЙСНО потрібно для продовження роботи програми.

Comment: @Yola Cамо собою, робота функції бути міняти стан програми(незалежно від того що повертає функція!) чи це буде нове значення глобальної змінної, редірект або нові значення в базі даних! Іноді функція буде повертати наприклад повний результат свого виконання(наприклад повноцінна сутність, яка була записана в базу даних), але це радше дуже рідкі винятки, а не правило.

Comment: @Yola Звідси, єдине узагальнення, яка має право на існування - `return type` - це тип даних, який повертає функція/метод. Якщо цей тип даних -  не `void`(нічого); дані, які поверне метод будуть важливою/потрібною інформацією для подальшої роботи програми та будуть відображати дії(зазвичай не повною мірою), які зробив цей метод/функція.

Comment: @improbable - це дуже хороша звичка намагатись писати програми так, щоб побічних ефектів було якнайменше. В функціональних мовах їх взагалі намагаються уникати. Код з функціями без побічних ефектів легше читати.

Comment: @improbable мені здається. що своїм варіантом перекладу podarok щось таке і стверджує.

Comment: @Yola В функціональних мовах, зміна стану, зазвичай, за межами скопу функції ніколи не відбувається. Але в об'єктно-орієнтованих мовах - це не завжди так, крім того "невидимі" дії, які здійснює функції далеко не завжди можна трактувати як зміну стану програми.

Comment: Згоден з коментарями вище, тип результату не зовсім коректно, тому що крім зміни глобального стану(i.e. side effect) все що завгодно може бути змінено якщо передається посилання(reference).

Comment: @Yola результат роботи фунція може і не повернути в програмуванні має чітке визначення - NULL або undefinded - що по суті своїй теж є результатом
Якщо повернення не відбулося і виконався Exception - це ніяк не впливає на суть _)

Comment: @podarok запитання про те як назвати той тип, що його можна побачити в сигнатурі функцій перед її назвою в таких мовах як C# чи C++. Що має чітке визначення? Який такий NULL? Бачу ви маєте досвід з python, то там цей тип не пишеться явно, а виводиться компілятором чи навіть віртуальною машиною, не знаю точно. Ось вам приклад `def my_function():
  print("Hello from a function")
  return 1`,
який тип результату тут? Адже результатом функції є виведення на екран і тимчасова цілочисельна змінна.

Comment: @Yola - тип результату mixed ;)

Comment: Ускладніть приклад - візьміть виконання функції у від'єднаному треді(`detach thread`). Результат може бути який завгодно, але тип повернення пустий.  
Або розглянемо сучасний С++ , з атрибутом `[[noreturn]]`. Повернення до точки виклику взагалі не відбудеться, але щось у результаті таки буде.

Answer (score -1):

Йдеться про function/method return type. Його майже завжди скорочують до function/method type. Тобто кажуть: "**Булева функція** IsValid" чи "**Строковий метод** GetLastError". На початку власне і йде **тип даних**, який повертає функція чи метод.

> Тип даних — характеристика, яку явно чи неявно надано об'єкту
>   (змінній, **функції**, полю запису, константі, масиву тощо). Тип даних
>   визначає множину припустимих значень, формат їхнього збереження,
>   розмір виділеної пам'яті та набір операцій, які можна робити над
>   даними.
>
> (c) Стаття "[Тип даних](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85)" з вікі

Тобто маємо термін **тип даних функції**, який програмісти не вагаючись скорочують до **тип функції**. Замість слова **функція** можна використати **процедура**

Якщо дуже хочеться наголосити, що це **тип значення, що повертається**, то можна сказати **тип результату функції** або, знову ж таки, **тип результату** чи **тип даних результату**

> In computer programming, the return type (or **result type**) defines and
>   constrains the data type of the value returned from a subroutine or
>   method.
>
> (c) Стаття "[Return type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_type)" з англійської вікі

N.B. Для вікі я би порадив варіант **тип результату** який є дослівним та змістовним перекладом англійського **result type**

Comment: Я не чув такого як *строковий метод ..* Для мене це звучить дуже не звично.

Comment: Якби мені хтось сказав *рядковий метод*, то я б, мбауть, подумав, що на увазі мається метод рядка, як-от *string.ToUpper*.

Comment: @Yola, це запозичення з російської (від *строка*). Чому ні?!. Якщо принципово, то можна використати запозичене з англійської стрінговий (від *string*). "Рядковий" мені дуже вухо ріже.

Comment: суть не в тому *рядок* чи *строка*, я писав про інше

Comment: А, у вас концептуальне заперечення. 
"В більшості мов програмування високого рівня, підпрограми називаються процедурами та функціями. В залежності від мови програмування, терміни «процедура» та «функція» можуть розрізнятися (як правило, процедурою називають підпрограму, що не повертає результату, тоді як функція має результат і може використовуватись як частина виразу) чи розглядатись як синоніми (зокрема, в мові C, де в початковому варіанті всі підпрограми могли повертати результат, їх здебільшого називають функціями)." (с)wiki
В побуті, їх частенько використовують як синоніми.

Comment: і не про це. я казав про форму. *строковий метод* найбільше асоціюється з методом *строки*. Уривок з вікі у відповіді не підходить до вашого варіанту, тому, що тип функції також включає типи параметрів і модифікатори.

Comment: Так, у терміну *строковий метод* є і ваше побічне значення. Але його дуже рідко вживають у цьому контексті. Щоб уникнути плутанини, якщо потрібен метод об'єкту, то кажуть "метод <ім'я класу>" (метод стрінга) чи "метод класу <ім'я класу>"(метод класу стрінг).
Є ще нефахова, споживацька термінологія. У них усе заплутано. Там прикметник може означати з чим працює метод, тобто  які дані він приймає *ЧИ* повертає.  Ось, для прикладу, з керівництва користувача Excel: "Логічні функції", "Функції дати й часу" і т.і..

Comment: Ви своїми прикладами самі собі заперечили. Функції дати і часу працюють з датою і часом і не обов'язково повертають дату і час. А логічні функції - це функції, які виконують логічні операції. Також слово логічні і булеві - це не синоніми.

Comment: «Його майже завжди скорочують до function/method type» — може, десь і скорочують, але я вважаю, що це категорично неправильно. Якщо функція (процедура) оголошена як «func f(a: int, b: string): bool» (або в стилі Сі — «bool f(int a, string b)»), то її типом буде «func(a: int, b: string): bool» (або в стилі Сі — «bool(int, string)»). Тип функції і тип її результату (тип, що вона повертає) — це зовсім різні речі. Але проти фраз «рядкова/цілочисельна/булева функція» нічого не маю (так склалося ще в математиці; хоча в новачків це викликає нерозуміння, мовляв, «це про аргументи чи результат?»).

Comment: Yola, не зовсім. Ви мали помітити, що то речення починалося з  "Є ще нефахова, споживацька термінологія. У них усе заплутано." Sasha, ви про сувору типізацію типу функції/процедури яку вимагає компілятор для декларації користувацьких подій, делегатів і такого іншого. Тут йдеться про розмовні скорочення. Переважна більшість сприймає прикметник як тип результату, бо параметрів методу зазвичай багато і кількість їх з часом росте, а результат один. І навіть якщо немає результату, хитрі програмісти придумали фіктивний тип результату void, який і означає, що жодного результату не повертається.

Comment: Я довго вагався, але все ж мінусанув через *тип фукнції*.

Comment: Гарно у Вас тут. Я витратив годину свого часу, а мені за це ще й мінус. Ну, норм :)

Comment: Ні, вас мінус не за це. І я його поставив для того, щоб наступні читачі обережніше ставились до вашого допису. Зауважте, що Sasha теж вважає варіант *тип функції* - неприпустимим.

Comment: -1 через тип функції. Якщо мова має строгу типізацію (наприклад, С ++), то там тип функції це не тільки значення, яке повертається, а й сигнатура.

Comment: Я проти «типу функції», але не певен, що відповідь заслуговує на мінус. (На мій погляд, вона могла б стати хорошою, якби прибрати про «тип функції» і залишити про прикметники («булева», «цілочисельна» тощо). Такі прикметники справді використовують, і найчастіше маючи на увазі саме результат функції. А не аргумент чи зовнішній клас (як пропонує Yola; от з зовнішнім класом у мене, наприклад, _рядкова функція_ чомусь зовсім не асоціюється). Але, звісно, такі зміни можуть вноситися лише на розсуд/за згодою автора.)